# I have a problem trying to add FBA Users or Roles to a SharePoint site

Tags: forms-authentication, publishing-site, 2007

I’ve added the membership and role provider keys for an FBA database into the web.config of a standard AD authenticated SharePoint site (as per Andrew Connells article).

This should then allow me to add roles and user to the site that can then be subsequently used to log in via an FBA configured Url.

When I add in a Role or User it should become underlined in the people picker dialog of the add user page, to show that the role/user has been recognised.

However this is the problem, I cannot get the roles or users to resolve and ‘underline’. I have other sites configured in exactly the same way and working correctly, I just can’t seem to get this site or any newly created sites to work as expected.

I’ve checked and rechecked my web.config entries, I’ve even pasted the entire web.config file from a site that works correctly into a problem site but I still can’t get the user or role to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you cross check below information

And if you are trying to add the FBA users via Central Admin Site for eg. for adding site administrators

Check if you have the below entries in the Central Admin Web.config

ConnectionString,ProviderInformation and the PeoplePicker that you have configured for FBA

And one more thing

Cross check this Authentication Provider Option for your current site in Central Site Administration site

1. Change the Authentication Type to Forms
2. Check Enable Anonymous Access
3. Enter Your_AspNetSqlMembershipProvider in the Membership providername
4. Enable Client Integration

This should solve the problem